# MS ACCESS - Adding items to Lookup Tables from a Master Query

Tags: ms-access

A seemingly simple question that has me stumped.

I have a table [Inventory] with the following fields: [Category], [ItemName], [Price].
ex: "Plumbing", "ACME Showerhead", $43
I have a table [Categories] with the fields [Category], [SubCategory]
ex. "Plumbing", "Hardware" or 
ex. "Flooring", "Wood"
I wish to have a form (ideally a standard grid) that allows me to enter new Inventory Records.
On this form would be the fields Inventory.Category, Categories.SubCategory, ItemName, Price.

When navigating to the field Inventory.Category, a drop down should allow me to select from Unique Categories.Category values. Once selected, the Subcategory field should allow me to select from valid subcategories of that Categories.Category. For example, if I chose "Plumbing" in the category field, I would only be presented with teh subcategory "Hardware" and not the subcategory "Wood".

I would also like the ability to add new Category Records while in this form, so I am not limited to whats in the dropdown. So for example, when adding a record to Inventory, if I want to create a new Category/SubCategory pair of say, "Plumbing", "Pipes", I should be able to do that without having to switch to another form/table or whatever.

Comment: This is a little confusing.. so you have a form that you're trying to do this on?

Comment: Hi, I tried updating the question to make it clearer - I hope I succeeded.